# R - Dashboard date in a shiny app deployed in shinyapps.io

Tags: r, date, shiny, shinydashboard

I've created a Dashboard in Shiny that is having new data 3 times a week, so I'm trying to show the last update date of my data in the credits using the command "**today()**" at the time I publish it, but when someone reload the Dashboard in shinyapps.io the update date is changing to that current date.

Is there any way to **fix the date when I publish it** without having to write it down manually?

Here is my code:

```
hcmap("countries/co/co-all", showInLegend = FALSE) %>%
hc_credits(enabled = TRUE,
           text = str_c("Data Source: www.---.com.<br/> Update Date:", format(today(), format="%d/%B/%Y"), sep = " "),
           style = list(fontSize = "11px"), position = list(align = "center",y = -35))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you already got the solution or not. Here is what I recently used.

You can use modified date of your data in UI. In global. R, use below command to get modified date of your data:

`updateDate <- format(file.info("file path")$mtime, "%Y-%m-%d")`

and then use `updateDate` instead of `today()`.

Comment: Thank you! The update date is working incredibly well!

Answer (score 0):

Shiny time is fluid on server and stale outside

```
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)
this_is_fixed <- now()

ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Time in the shiny world"),

  mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "fixed"),
      verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "fluid")

    )
  )


# Define server logic required to draw a histogram ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$fixed <- renderText({
    this_is_fixed
  })

  output$fluid <- renderText({
    now()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I've tried but the problem remains: date is changing every time users reload the Dashboard. 

#Outside ui and server
fixed <- format(today(), format="%d/%B/%Y") 

#Server
hcmap("countries/co/co-all", showInLegend = FALSE) %>%
hc_credits(enabled = TRUE,
           text = str_c("Data Source: www.---.com.<br/> Update Date:", fixed, sep = " "),
           style = list(fontSize = "11px"), position = list(align = "center",y = -35))